# How to resolve Socket.io Transport Polling error

Tags: javascript, socket.io, client-server

I am trying to make a real time chat app ,but stuck a bit,Here's my server side file

```
const express= require('express');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const http = require('https');

const {addUser,removeUser,getUser,getUserInRoom} = require('./users.js');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const router = require('./router');


const app= express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io= socketio(server);

io.on('connect',(socket)=>{
    socket.on('join',({name,room},callback)=>{
        const {error,user}=addUser({id:socket.id,name,room});

        if(error)
            return callback(error);

        socket.emit('message',{user: 'admin',text: `${user.name}, welcome to room ${user.room}`});
        
        socket.broadcast.to(user.room).emit('message',{user: 'admin', text :`${user.name}, has joined!`});

        socket.join(user.room);

        callback();

    });

    socket.on('sendMessage',(message,callback)=>{
         const user = getUser(socket.id);

         io.to(user.room).emit('message',{user: user.name, text : message});

         callback();
    });

    socket.on('disconnect',()=>{
        console.log('user left');
    })
});


app.use(router);


server.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000,()=>console.log(`Server has started on port ${PORT}`));
```

and here's my client side file

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import queryString from 'query-string';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

import './Chat.css';
import InfoBar from '../InfoBar/InfoBar';
import Input from '../Input/Input';

var socket;

const Chat = ( {location} ) => {
    const [name,setName]=useState('');
    const [room,setRoom]=useState('');
    const [message,setMessage] = useState('');
    const [messages,setMessages] = useState([]);
    const ENDPOINT = 'localhost:5000';

    useEffect(()=>{
        const {name,room} = queryString.parse(location.search);

        socket = io(ENDPOINT);
        
        //console.log(location.search);
        //console.log(data);
        setName(name);
        setRoom(room);

        //console.log(socket)
        socket.emit('join',{name,room},()=>{
            
        });

        return ()=>{
            socket.emit('disconnect');

            socket.off();
        } 
    }, [ENDPOINT,location.search]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        socket.on('message',(message)=>{
            setMessages([...messages,message]);
        })
    },[messages]);

    //function for sending messages

    const sendMessage = (event)=>{
        event.preventDefault();
        if(message){
            socket.emit('sendMessage',message,()=> setMessage(''));
        }
    }

    console.log(message,messages);

    return (
        <div className="outerContainer">
            <div className="container">
                <InfoBar room={room}/>
                <Input message={message} setMessage={setMessage} sendMessage={sendMessage} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Chat;
```

I also tried using io.connect() as mentioned in some other post but that doesn't help and get this error on usual.

polling-xhr.js:203 GET http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NNv75lE net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: Tested the same tutorial and got stuck. Nothing seems to help.